# Trying to retrieve refresh_token, token_uri, client_id, and client_secret using Swift and sending to backend for processing

Tags: swift, google-api, google-oauth

Trying to retrieve `authcode` and send it to backend to get `refresh_token`, `token_uri`, `client_id`, and `client_secret`. Everytime I try getting authCode using `let authCode = user.serverAuthCode`, `authCode` is *nil*.

```
func handleGoogleSignIn() {
    guard let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene,
          let rootViewController = scene.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow })?.rootViewController else {
        print("RootViewController not found")
        return
    }
    
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(withPresenting: rootViewController) { signInResult, error in
        guard error == nil else {
            print("Sign in error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        guard let signInResult = signInResult else { return }
        let authCode = signInResult.serverAuthCode
        signInResult.user.refreshTokensIfNeeded { user, error in
            guard error == nil else {
                print("Error refreshing tokens: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            guard let user = user, let idToken = user.idToken?.tokenString else { return }   
            guard let url = URL(string: "XXX") else {
                print("Invalid URL")
                return
            }
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            
            let jsonString = "{\"idToken\": \"\(idToken)\", \"email\": \"\(self.email)\"}"
            request.httpBody = Data(jsonString.utf8)
            
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error sending token to API: \(error)")
                    return
                }
                if let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    print("Response from API: \(dataString)")
                    return
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

I tried doing this to get `authCode`, but it is not working:

```
func handleGoogleSignIn() {
    guard let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene,
          let rootViewController = scene.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow })?.rootViewController else {
        print("RootViewController not found")
        return
    }
    
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(withPresenting: rootViewController) { signInResult, error in
        guard error == nil else { return }
        guard let signInResult = signInResult else { return }
        
        let authCode = signInResult.serverAuthCode
        print(authCode)
    }
}
```

I thought this would show `authCode`, but it is *nil*.